# How to save created csv into cloudinary cloud?

Tags: python, django, cloudinary

I am developing a data science project, I scrape specific site data, created a dataframe and saved in csv format. Now, i want to save that file to my cloudinary account as a file storage.

```
class NepseApi(APIView):
authentication_classes = []
permission_classes = []
def get(self, request, format=None):
    level2=[]
    rng=get_range(request, 8)
    table_Datas=get_url(request)
    level1= pd.Series(table_Datas).drop_duplicates().tolist()

    for k in level1:
        if len(k)> 35:
            level2.append(k)
        else:
            pass
    d=[]
    for l in range(1, len(level2)):
        c= level2[l].split('\n')
        d.append(c)
    df= pd.DataFrame(d[1:], columns=d[0])
    date= pd.Timestamp.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    df['date']= date
    df_csv = df.to_csv(date +'.csv', index=True)
    df.rename(columns={'Traded Companies': 'company_name','No. Of Transaction': 'no_of_transaction', 'Max Price':'max_price','Min Price':'min_price','Closing Price':'closing_price','Traded Shares':'traded_shares','Previous Closing':'previous_closing','Difference Rs.':'difference_rs'}, inplace=True)
    jsn = json.loads(df.to_json(orient='records'))

    return Response(jsn)
```

df_csv = df.to_csv(date +'.csv', index=True) # How to create path to save file?

Comment: Cloudinary accepts a local file path or a URL to the file. Once you have the file location, it should be relatively easy to upload it to Cloudinary: https://cloudinary.com/documentation/django_integration#quick_example_file_upload
Make sure to pass resource_type=raw

Comment: Yeah i understand what you are saying, but i want to scrape some website and generate csv and then save that to the cloudinary rather than straight forward upload. Can you help me further?